Asking question for which I know the answer
Is it ok to ask a question that I think is relevant for this community (and for which there doesn't seem to be an easily-found answer via google) even if I know the answer?
It seems we have a paucity of questions here, which will affect the site's long-term success.  Most of the questions I would ask are either basic ones (where I know the answer) or obscure ones (where I don't know the answer, but they are probably of limited interest).

Yes, it is ok. It has already been done. Etiquette suggests that you should wait for an answer from someone else.

According to the documented policy, it is OK to answer your own question, and even encouraged.  Personally, I think it answering your own question is fine, and something we should encourage if both the question and answer are good ones.  I don't think we should discriminate against cases where there's an answer from the person who asked the question.
However, I have had experience where I wondered if I'd been singled out for special scrutiny because I answered my own question (even though everyone gave other reasons, I still wondered), so I've drawn the inference that it is allowed but may sometimes be viewed with suspicion and may not always be encouraged.  Of course, with a sample size of n=1, I would hesitate to draw too many conclusions.
Regardless of my personal experience, I have the impression that there are some people who view answering your own question with skepticism and view it as a potential sign of gaming the system (see also here and here and here), and you may see downvotes or demands to mark your question as a community wiki, regardless of the official policy, particularly if people think (rightly or wrongly) that you are just seeking rep points.  People behave in all sorts of interesting ways, regardless of what the official policy may say.  So, just be prepared for it and wear a thick skin.

FWIW, the MathSE community has addressed this several time. Here and here are good sources of slightly contradictory viewpoints on the topic. In general, they think it perfectly reasonable to post and accept your own answer. It's in the faq, for that matter.
